# Mockito spy: also spy on members?

Tags: java, mockito

When I spy on a class, does it also spy on all the members in that class? For example, say I'm making a Pair class, and testing the implementation of toString (not the best example of all time).

```
public class Pair<L,R> {
    L left;
    R right;
    // ... getters setters etc
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + getLeft() + ", " + getRight() + ")";
    }
}
```

Say I want to ensure that both left and right their toString called.

```
@Test
public void testToString() {
    classUnderTest = spy(new Pair<>(...));
    String str = classUnderTest.toString();

    verify(classUnderTest.getLeft()).toString(); // does it actually verify?
    verify(classUnderTest.getRight()).toString();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you test it? Read that before you do: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-verify-tostring

Comment: @Compass no, it's correct as it is.

Comment: @JBNizet - they do pass. After reading some more, this looks like it means that it behaves as expected -- I didn't know verify failed if you didn't pass it a mock/spy. toString here was just an example, my real code is different.

Comment: No, they don't pass. If they do, then you're not testing it correctly. Post a complete minimal example reproducing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't verify `toString()` method call. Please see [documentation](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) for more details.

However, if you want to make sure, that when calling `toString()`,  methods `getLeft()` and `getRight` are called, you can write something like this:

```
@Test
    public void whenPrintingPairBothPartsAreRequested() {
        Pair<String, Integer> pair = new Pair<>();
        pair = spy(pair);

        verify(pair).getLeft();
        verify(pair).getRight();
    }
```

**EDIT**: No, spying an object won't spy all it's members, unless you will explicitly set object's member as a spy.

The reason why it works fine in your example is just a coincidence.

When you write `verify(pair.getLeft()).toString()` it's actually eq to `verify(pair.getLeft())` (so, `toString()` will be ignored). But don't be confused: it's not `toString()` on the pair object. It's `toString()` of that Left object inside of pair object.

`public static <T> T verify(T mock)` - is a signiture of verify method.
So, if you are verifying `verify(pair.getLeft())`, `pair.getLeft()` will be returned. And after that, you call `toString()` on it, that will has no use and no influence to test results.

Comment: apparently toString is a bad example. My real code isn't testing toString, rather than the members have their own converter method called when the owner is converted.